# Running protractor with spring-boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, protractor

i wan´t to run end2end-test for my angular (7) application in a buildserver (bamboo). The application runs with spring-boot (2.1.x) as backend (java - microfrontend). So my problem is, how can i call protractor-tests from my (integration-)tests which runs an embedded sping-boot.

I know there is selenium (and also two other projects which aren´t maintenanced) for java but protractor has much more features for angular.

Can i call single tests from protractor in a command-line which i call from the java-code? Or anything else?

Thanks (and sorry for my english)
René

Comment: You are using maven then you can try frontend-maven-plugin

Comment: Yes i´m using maven. But i want to run the protrator tests with a running spring-boot (embedded because the java-integrationtests starts such a server)

Answer (score 0):

You can try maven execute command plug-in. Call your spring Boot with profile to run first (i.e local profile with H2 database) and then call ng e2e with environment that points to your local spring Boot you started.

This approach is still not as integrated though. I am also looking for better way of doing this.